# 3dsmax FFD transform control point manipulation by script

Tags: controls, 3dsmax, maxscript

Hello everyone interested in maxscript,

I would like to make a batch of rock models deformed by FFD. To achieve efficiency, I need to write a script to manipulate the control points for random deformation.

I opened the listener and move the control point manually, but no message pop up to offer reference. So it seems hard for me to solve this problem on myself.

Could you kindly give me a concise example on how to do that? Thank you very much!!!

Best,

Yiyang

Answer (score 0):

FFD control points are animated like editable mesh vertexes.
Hopefully this will work:

```
b = box()
addmodifier b (FFD_2x2x2())
animateAll b.modifiers[#FFD_2x2x2]
getPropNames b.modifiers[#FFD_2x2x2] #dynamicOnly --prints properties which you can animate
with animate on
(
    at time 50
        b.modifiers[#FFD_2x2x2].Control_Point_1 = [0,-2,0]
)
playanimation()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a nice example for new users to look into. I will post my code later. Best regards!